# Finding the coefficient of $x^r$ in exponential series: $\frac{e^{nx}-1}{1-e^{-x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, power-series, exponentiation, closed-form

Find the coefficient of $x^r$ in the expansion of $$\frac{e^{nx}-1}{1-e^{-x}}$$
I try to simplify it but I was no susessful .so I try to merely expand it but I found it so difficult to compute $x^r$ term . so please anyone give me hint to solve it .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\frac{u^n-1}{u-1}=1+u+\cdots+u^{n-1}, \qquad u\neq 1,
$$ giving
$$
\frac{e^{nx}-1}{1-e^{-x}}=e^x\cdot\frac{e^{nx}-1}{e^x-1}=e^x+e^{2x}+\cdots+e^{nx}, \qquad e^x\neq 1,
$$ then one may recall that
$$
e^{ax}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k!}x^k.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot sir...I just forget the formula that you used in our first step .thanks for recall it .now I go and try to solve it sir .

Comment: is there any formula for $$1^r+2^r+3^r+...+n^r$$ where n,r$\in$ N sir?

Comment: I think the answer is $$\frac{1^r+2^r+...+n^r}{r!}$$ is it right sir?

Comment: @SathasivamK Yes, it's the right answer. There is a formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula